# how i can prevent same entry at same time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tripexpense  system.

The situation is: two or more users register at the same time with same record and both are success.

Whereas one of them should get a success and the rest should get an error.

Comment: Can you post the code that creates 'the same record' and the table definition.  Also what do you mean by 'the same record'.

Comment: same record like email id. If user already register with email id and onther user  try with same email id then he/she not success it show message try with different email but  if we can use same email id at same time and click sign up button then both are success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do in this way,

```
ALTER TABLE Users ADD UNIQUE (email_id);
```

So in this way for same user with email id wont create two entries.
You can apply unique constraint to relevant field if its not email_id.